# Wondering what I am doing wrong with this program?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to get the program to run from 4 column of the seasons, and 2 columns for years 2016 and 2017. The input is rainfall for both years for each season. It is allowing me to enter numbers for times for winter and then stops and it is not calculating right. Any help as to what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Read(double rainfall[][4], int row);
void Calculate(double rainfall[][4], int row);
void Write(double rainfall[][4], int row);

int main()
{
    double rainfall[2][4];
    int row = 2;
    Read(rainfall, row);
    Calculate(rainfall, row);
    Write(rainfall, row);
}

void Read(double rainfall[][4], int row)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            cout << "Enter rainfall for Winter: " << endl;
        else if (i == 1)
            cout << "Enter rainfall for Spring: " << endl;
        else if (i == 2)
            cout << "Enter rainfall for Summer: " << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cout << j + 1 << " : " << endl;
            cin >> rainfall[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void Calculate(double rainfall[2][4], int row)
{
    int i, j;
    double row_sum;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        row_sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            row_sum = row_sum + rainfall[i][j];
        }
        rainfall[i][4] = row_sum;
    }

    double col_sum;
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        col_sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < row - 1; i++)
        {
            col_sum = col_sum + rainfall[i][j];
        }
        rainfall[2][j] = col_sum;
    }
}

void Write(double rainfall[][4], int row)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            cout << rainfall[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is C?  Please tag with a programming language.

Comment: "rainfall[i][4] = row_sum;" Here you are accessing a out of bound element.

Comment: in Read: for(int i = 0; i < row -1; i++)  I think you want to remove the "-1" from this.

Comment: `row = 2` and loop condition `i < row - 1` meaning, i = 0 will be allowed (winter).. i = 1 will not be allowed. so stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < row - 1; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
```

In C++, you should use std::vector or std::array instead and avoid C style arrays, that way you get better help when you go out-of-bounds with your array which I think is happening in more places than one.